# When do you use XPath over XmlDocument or XmlTextReader?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xpath, xmldocument

When do you use XPath over XmlDocument?

I'm trying to see things from a higher level. Is there a situation where it is better to use XPath over XmlDocument?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Question 777777! (just for interest)

Comment: A nice comparison between XPathDocument and XMLDocument: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eh3exdc4.aspx

Answer (score 4):

XPath and XmlDocument are not exclusive things. XPath is a language defined by W3C to allow XML documents to be queried using a path-like syntax. XmlDocument is a .NET class that abstracts away much regarding XML parsing. XmlDocument has methods such as `SelectNodes` and `SelectSingleNode` that take XPath expressions as parameters and return you the results.

I don't understand why you seem to think that XPath and XmlDocument can't be used together, or maybe I'm misunderstanding you completely.

Answer (score 3):

When there is some reason to need an [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmldocument) rather than an [`XPathDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument) or [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.), both of which support XPath with lighter weight in memory models.

[`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmlreader) is good for reading a document linearly, but has not immediate support for XPath, but all the other three APIs do, but they vary with their support for other functionality. If you are looking to extract data consider `XPathDocument` (designed around XPath) or `XDocument` (enables LINQ to XML type approach) rather than `XmlDocument`.